# Testing actors using dependency injection in play framework 2.4.x

Tags: playframework, akka, guice, playframework-2.4

How do I test an actor that is created by dependency injection? In my application I can get an ActorRef by named injection:

```
public MyClass {
    @Inject
    @Named("ping")
    ActorRef mPingRef;
}
```

How do I get this reference in my tests?

This is my actor:

```
public class PingActor extends UntypedActor {
    @Inject
    public PingActor(Configuration configuration) {
         ... // Use config
    }


    @Override
    public void onReceive(Object message) throws Exception {
        if (message instanceof Ping) {
            getSender().tell(new Pong(), getSelf());
        }
    }

    public static class Ping {}
    public static class Pong {}
}
```

I have configured my application with my own module:

```
public class MyModule extends AbstractModule implements AkkaGuiceSupport {
    private final Configuration mConfig;

    public MyModule(Environment environment, Configuration configuration){
        this.mConfig = configuration;
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure() {
        bindActor(PingActor.class, "ping");
    }
}
```

The module is enabled in application.conf:

```
play.modules.enabled += "com.my.package.MyModule"
```

Answer (score 4):

This solution is for `PlayScala`, but it should be the same mechanism for your `PlayJava`:

So I got my `GuiceModule`:

```
class CommonModule extends AbstractModule with AkkaGuiceSupport {
  override def configure(): Unit = {
    bindActor[SomeActor]("actor-name")
  }
}
```

Then the test (I stripped some stuff from my test, so it may not compile directly):

```
import akka.actor.{ActorRef, ActorSystem}
import akka.testkit.{TestKit, TestProbe}
import module.CommonModule
import org.specs2.mutable.Specification
import org.specs2.specification.Scope
import play.api.inject._
import play.api.inject.guice.GuiceApplicationBuilder
import play.api.test.Helpers._

class SwitchUpdateActorSpec extends Specification {

  "MyActor" should {

    val actorSystem = ActorSystem("test")
    class Actors extends TestKit(actorSystem) with Scope

    val app = new GuiceApplicationBuilder(modules = Seq(new CommonModule))
      .overrides(bind[ActorSystem].toInstance(actorSystem))
      .build()


    "respond with 'ok' upon receiving a message" in new Actors {
      running(app) {
        private val injector: Injector = app.injector
        private val actor: ActorRef = injector.instanceOf(BindingKey(classOf[ActorRef]).qualifiedWith("actor-name"))

        val probe = TestProbe()
        actor.tell("hi there!", probe.ref)

        probe.expectMsg("ok")
      }
    }
  }    
}
```

So what I did was:

- create a fresh `ActorSystem`
- wrap that `actorSystem` in Akka's `TestKit` (`libraryDependencies += "com.typesafe.akka" %% "akka-testkit" % "2.4.1"`)
- use the `GuiceApplicationBuilder` to apply the override
- and then use the `app.injector` directly to get access to my guice configured actor

It becomes quite obviously what happens, when you look into the implementation of `bindActor` that you are using in your `MyModule.configure()` method:

```
  def bindActor[T <: Actor: ClassTag](name: String, props: Props => Props = identity): Unit = {
    accessBinder.bind(classOf[ActorRef])
      .annotatedWith(Names.named(name))
      .toProvider(Providers.guicify(Akka.providerOf[T](name, props)))
      .asEagerSingleton()
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

Im writing actor unit tests as such

```
static ActorSystem system;
static Configuration configuration;
static MyActor myActor;

@BeforeClass
public static void setup() {
    Map<String, Object> stringConf = new HashMap<>();
    configuration = new Configuration(stringConf);

    system = ActorSystem.apply();
    final Props props = Props.create(MyActor.class, configuration);
    final TestActorRef<MyActor> ref = TestActorRef.create(system, props, "myActor");
    myActor = ref.underlyingActor();
}

@AfterClass
public static void teardown() {
    JavaTestKit.shutdownActorSystem(system);
    system = null;
}
```

then you can call methods in your actor as if it were a regular java class. According to the play framework https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/JavaFunctionalTest

> It’s generally best practice to inject members only in functional tests and to manually create instances in unit tests.

so thats what im doing here. You will need a dependency on

```
"com.typesafe.akka" % "akka-testkit_2.11" % "2.4.12" % "test"
```

for this to work. Hope this helps.